# Show that the row space of $A^+$ and the row space of $A^T$ are equal.

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

A psuedo inverse of a matrix $A$ is defined as a matrix $A^+$ that satisfies $AA^+A=A, A^+AA^+=A^+$ such that $AA^+$ and $A^+A$ are symmetric.
Show that the row space of $A^+$ and the row space of $A^T$ are equal.

I have no idea how to start this. I was thinking of showing that the row space of $A^+$ is a subset of the row space of $A^T$ and vice versa.
I tried like this:
Let $x$ be a member of the row space of $A^+$.
Then $x$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the rows of $A^+$.
I used the fact that
$(A^+)^T=(A^T)^+$. But I cannot proceed further.
Can someone please give me some hint?

Comment: Row space of $A^T$ is the column space of $A$ and is the range of $A$ ( consists of al vectors $Av$). Can you use that?

Comment: @markvs; But how does that relate to $A^+$?

Comment: Consider $B=(A^+)^T$. Then you want  to compare range of $B$ with range of $A$.

Comment: @markvs; yes that is true, but how do I show they are equal